# Как закрыть программу с разрешения юзера на пайтон

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

Я создал программу который при нажатия на кнопку Выход появится окно который спросит "Вы уверены что хотите выйти?" когда нажму на "Да" ничего не произойдёт. Надо это исправить.
Вот код:

```
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox as mbox


def OnQuest():
    mbox.askquestion("Вопрос", "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти?")

root=Tk()
root.title('Exit?')
root.geometry('600x400')
root['background']= None

menubar=Menu(root)
filemenu=Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
filemenu.add_command(label="Выход", command=OnQuest)
menubar.add_cascade(label="Файл", menu=filemenu)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В функцию `OnQuest():` добавьте следующий код и измените `askquestion` на `askyesno`:

```
def OnQuest():
    quest = mbox.askyesno("Вопрос", "Вы уверены, что хотите выйти?")
    if quest == True:
        root.quit()
```

Когда Вы нажимаете на "Да" переменной `quest`, присваивается значение `True`, а когда на "Нет" `False`. Метод `quit()` завершает программу.